Creating a random Markov matrix using Numpy
A Markov matrix is a matrix whose rows sum to 1 and whose determinant is 1 (at least according to one definition).
I am able to make a unimodular matrix using the following operation:
b = b/(np.linalg.det(b)**(1/3))

And I am able to make the rows sum to 1 using the following operation:
b = b/b.sum(axis=1).reshape(3,1)

But these operations do not work together. Is there a way to create a random matrix with both of the properties I need?

Are you sure the determinant must be 1?

A stochastic matrix with determinant 1 is a permutation matrix - i.e. it represents a deterministic process, not a stochastic one.  For example, a unity matrix is technically a stochastic matrix with determinant 1, and represents a "process" with no transitions.  See also
